# Eclipse Luna (version 4.4.2) "Referenced Libraries" folder not visible

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse Luna (version 4.4.2): In Java projects the "Referenced Libraries" folder is not visible from the "Project Explorer" view. All External jars are shown directly in the project folder root. No issues with compiles and runs.

How to make the Referenced Libraries folder visible?

Answer (score 0):

May be you confuse the "Project Explorer" with the "Package Explorer".
The "Project Explorer" never shows a "Referenced Libraries" folder.
But the "Package Explorer" does what you want, because it is optimized for Java projects.